# Getting input from console in Java: Is it blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a Java program in which I read a line from Console, and do some processing around it. The processing might take 1-2 seconds (i.e. takes longer than the input rate), while I might keep receiving 50 lines per second.

Although there were some similar questions, they were addressing C/C++ and not Java. So my fundamental question is below:

While still processing an input/line, am I blocked from receiving new inputs? Or somehow they are queued in the system/JVM? Or better ask this way: **Do I miss any lines while processing takes time?** I don't want to miss any lines by any means.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNext()){
    //process line. Can take 1-2 seconds.
    processInput(sc.nextLine());
}
sc.close();
```

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I came up with making my code more thread-friendly, using `Executors`:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
while (sc.hasNext()) {
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                processInput(sc.nextLine());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: If `processInput()` doesn't run stuff in another thread, yes, then it waits until processing is finished and gets the next line, then. But `System.in` is a data stream. You won't "miss" any lines just because you take your time reading from the stream.

Comment: @mumpitz Good point. I should run `processInput` in a new thread. Just wondering, where are those upcoming messages stacked?! :)

Comment: @TinaJ they aren't ;) You won't be able to input another line until `process()` finishes. Because only **after** this, it let's you input the next line.

Comment: I heard better to have a pool of executors where they can do `processInput`. Any examples how to implement that?

Comment: @mumpitz yes no stacked...I mean the input is entered in console, but I still don't receive them in my code as new line. So where are they buffered meanwhile?

Comment: in general: yes stdin is "blocking". That means: it blocks when it runs out of input(waiting for new data) or  the buffer is full(waiting for data to be read). Eg if you read a value from stdin, the user hasn't given yet, the program stops until the user has given the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare these two samples:

Frist, linear without multiple threads:

```
public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleClass instance = new SampleClass();
        instance.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        while (!(input = sc.nextLine()).equals("exit")) {
            processInput(input);
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    private void processInput(String input) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("input: " + input);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, using a new thread for every input processing:

```
public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleClass instance = new SampleClass();
        instance.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        while (!(input = sc.nextLine()).equals("exit")) {
            processInput(input);
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    private void processInput(String input) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("input: " + input);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

}
```

Just try it. In both cases you don't miss input, but the difference is that without new threads the processing time adds up (of course) - it doesn't run parallel.

Comment: Cool. Yes that's the way to go. But here you add up threads every seconds, right?! Can you check my update to see if my use of `executors` is correct?

Comment: A new thread is started everytime a new input is received. Then this thread waits for 2 seconds before printing the input to stdout and exiting. I haven't worked with executors myself, but it looks good and very practical.

Answer (score 0):

It is blocking, although the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) could have been clearer: It keeps saying *"A scanning operation may block waiting for input."* While it could theoretically throw a NoSuchElementException instead of blocking, it seems to me that this is up to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Question is more on: Do I miss any inputs while processing takes time?

Comment: In principle, no. But notice that "A Scanner is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization."

Comment: ummm, how can I make my snippet efficient then? I heard about executors. Can you post a sample, if that's what would help?

Comment: If the thread processing is done within _processInput_ you could use an executor.

Comment: @Jonathan for the real world you are 100% right, but I think they can't be more specific as blocking is done by the os

Comment: @kai Whether the OS reads ahead or not, from the Java point of view the scanner blocks until input is available or throws an exception.

Comment: well thats about my point; its not the scanner but stdin that causes the block. if stdin just returned(eg with no input) scanner wouldn't block either. (but thats a big "if" that doesn't matter in the real world) – kai